# Aggregate Function in Pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am currently doing a Pymongo project and I am having a lot of trouble with getting the documents between two dates:

When I do this it works perfectly and it gets me every document from date trimestre1 onwards:

```
trim2 = mycol1.find({"date_anounced":{'$gte': trimestre1}})
```

However if I try any of the next 2 options, I get no documents at all. What could be the problem?

```
trim2 = mycol1.find({"date_anounced":{'$gte': trimestre1,$lt:timestre2}})

**OR** 

trim2 = mycol1.aggregate([{"$match": {'$and':[{'date_anounced': {'$gte': trimestre1}},{'date_anounced': {'$lt': trimestre2}}]}}])
```

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: The output depends upon the input values in `trimestre1` and `trimestre2` _and_ the field value of `date_anounced`.

Comment: They are as follows: `trimestre1 = datetime(2019,3,1,0,0,0).isoformat()` and `trimestre2 = datetime(2019,6,1,0,0,0).isoformat()`. This format yielded no problem when using `$gte:`, problem comes when inserting the 2 dates and searching for the documents in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead,  https://mongoplayground.net/p/QUycXEiOR-L

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    "$match": {
      "date_anounced": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")
      }
    }
  },
])
```

Comment: Worked pefectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SantiagoFernndezdelCastillo You're welcome, don't forget to approve and upvote!!